# Interval approximation with a Taylor polynomial

Tags: calculus

I'm looking for help understanding this problem.

> Let $f(x) = e^{-x^2}$
>
> 1. Find the 6th degree polynomial centered at zero.

My answer: $$1- x^2 + {x^4\over 4} - {x^6\over 6}$$

> 2. Estimate the interval on which $T_6(x)$ approximates $e^{-x^2}$ to within $0.01$.

I'm really not sure what to do here. I know that $$e^{-x^2} = \sum_n{(-x^2)^n\over n!}$$

> 3. Evaluate $T_6(x)$ at $-1$ and Compare this to the estimate of $e^{-1}$.

Should I enter $-1$ for $x$ into the $6$th degree polynomial I found in #1?

> 4. What other two methods could be used to determine the accuracy of this estimate?

Comment: Answer (1) is wrong; take a closer look at your answer to (2). For (2), use the Alternating Series Test. For (3): yes, but find the right polynomial first. Qustion (4): this should be in your textbook.

Comment: The term $x^4/4$ should be $x^4/2$.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x)=e^x$ has a fourth derivative $g^{i v}=g.$  We have  $$e^x-(1+x+x^2/2!+x^3/3!)=g^{i v}(y)x^4/4!= e^y x^4/4!$$ where  $y$ is between $x$ and $0$ when $x\ne 0.$ So $$e^{-x^2}-(1-x^2+x^4/2!-x^6/3!)=e^{-y^2}x^8/4!$$ where  $y^2$ is between $x^2$ and $0$ when $x\ne 0.$ Since $0<e^{-y^2}< 1$ when $y\ne 0,$ we have $$0<x^8<0.24 \implies |e^{-y^2}x^8/4!|=e^{-y^2}x^8/4! <x^8/4!<0.01.$$ And of course the error in the approximation is $0$ when $x=0.$